# Access windows native message dialog box windowtester

Tags: java, swt, swtbot, window-tester

I am a new to this. I am working on WindowTester.I could not open a new discussion page or I would tag it as Windowtester
I am having difficulty of closing down windows native dialog box after pull down menu. The code is,

```
ui.click(new PullDownMenuItemLocator("Save Control ", new ViewLocator("com.SOAGateway.control.views.SOAGView")));
```

After choosing one of the option from the menu, a dialog box appear which is native window dialog.
I would like to cancel it but it is not working.
I tried different things such as,

a)

```
ui.click(new PullDownMenuItemLocator("Save Control ", new    ViewLocator("com.SOAGateway.control.views.SOAGView")));
Display display = new Display();
if (shell != null) shell.dispose();
```

b)

```
Display display = new Display();
ui.click(new PullDownMenuItemLocator("Save Control ", new ViewLocator("com.SOAGateway.control.views.SOAGView")));
display.dispose();
```

But nothing is working.

Is there any idea how could I sort out this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interaction with native Dialogs is [very limited](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wintester/html/faq/faq?hl=de#DoesWindowTestersupportnativedialogslikeFileOpenFileSaveetc.) in Windowtester.
However, you should be able to cancel a native dialog in Windows with the following line of code:

```
ui.keyClick(WT.ESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

SWTBOT can't handle native dialogs - see http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ#How_do_I_use_SWTBot_to_test_native_dialogs_.28File_Dialogs.2C_Color_Dialogs.2C_etc.29.3F

Comment: I could not open a new discussion page or I would tag it as Windowtester. I am working with window tester. Sorry I should mentioned it somewhere. thanks